# How to change caption setup for appendix?

Tags: captions, justification

I am writing a paper with an appendix (for master thesis) and for the paper I want the captions to be aligned to the left. But for the appendix, the captions should be centered.
For the paper, I used this setup in the preamble:

```
\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=off}
```

But for the appendix, I want the captions to be centered.
I tried to renew the command for the caption setup like this:

```
\renewcommand\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=on}
```

So turning singlelinecheck to 'on'. But it doesn't work.

How does this work? I am quite new with LaTeX, so maybe I just don't understand the renewcommand?

Thank you in advance!

I divided my report into a main file, and in this file, I add all the chapters, which are separate files. Maybe it is not possible when I do it like this?
This is (a summary of) the main file:

```
\documentclass[10pt, mathptmx,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{Packages}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}
\author{Anne Derks\,}
\title{Master Thesis Sandwich Panels}
\input{Input_titlepage}
\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}
\include{Titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\begin{flushleft}
\large\textbf{PREFACE}\\
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{PREFACE}
\normalsize
\lipsum[1]
\end{flushleft}

\newpage
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\end{flushleft}
 
\vspace{60pt}

\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{ABSTRACT:} 
\hfill 
\\
\vspace{12pt}

\textbf{KEYWORDS:} \hspace{1mm} Sandwich Panels, Geometric Non-Linear Buckling, Connection Failure.
\end{flushleft}
 \vspace{24pt}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{INTRODUCTION}\label{section:Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1_Introduction}  

\section{THEORETICAL BACKGROUND}\label{section:Literature}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2_Literature}            

\section{ANALYTICAL MODEL}\label{section:Analytical_model}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3_AnalyticalModel}   

\renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{REFERENCES}
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{APPENDIX}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=on}

\newpage
\section{Drawings Cembrit Cetris Basis tests}
\label{Appendix:Cembrit}
\input{Appendices/AppendixH_Cembrit_drawings}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=off}

\newpage
\section{Results sandwich panel test}
\input{Appendices/AppendixL_Panel_results}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just remove the `\renewcommand` and everything should work fine. You don't want to change the command `\captionsetup`, but you want to apply it.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know it was that simple. I tried so many more complicated things. Thank you so much, it works!

Comment: But one more question, when I again want to change it, it does not work anymore. There are some tables in the appendix for which I want the caption to be aligned to the left instead of centered. I changed the captionsetup to singlelinecheck=on at the beginning of the appendix to center the captions. When I want to change this to 'off' before a table or at the beginning of a page, it does not work. Instead, it just displays the text: 'format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=on' in the document. Why is this not possible?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer and also addressed your follow-up question there.

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand` is used for, well, renewing commands. In your case you don't want to renew the command, but to apply it. Therefore deleting `\renewcommand` should be fine.

It is possible to use `\captionsetup` multiple times in your document, as you can see in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small,singlelinecheck=off}% Setup for main part
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% figure in main part
    \centering \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck} \caption{First caption.}
\end{figure}
% adapt setup for appendix:
\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small,singlelinecheck=on}
\begin{figure}% figure in appendix
    \centering \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck} \caption{Second caption.}
\end{figure}
% adapt setup for second part of appendix:
\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small,singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{figure}% figure in second part of appendix
    \centering \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck} \caption{Third caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

### Edit after comment

Sorry, it is quite hard to get something meaningful out of your code as I don't have all your files. Even when I try to reduce your code to an MWE it still works.

```
\documentclass[10pt, mathptmx,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,lipsum,multicol,graphicx}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{figure} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First image}
\end{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{INTRODUCTION}\label{section:Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\section{THEORETICAL BACKGROUND}\label{section:Literature}
\lipsum[1]         

\section{ANALYTICAL MODEL}\label{section:Analytical_model}
\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}

\newpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{APPENDIX}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=on}


\newpage
\section{Drawings Cembrit Cetris Basis tests}
\label{Appendix:Cembrit}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{First image}
\end{figure}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it,skip=6pt,font=small, singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{figure} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{First image}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\section{Results sandwich panel test}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes that is indeed what I did, but when I change it the third time it does not work. It just displays the text within the caption setup in the document. I added my main document above, maybe it has something to do with the setup of my document? 
Also, when I just change it before a figure, so before the \begin{figure} it also does not work and displays the text in the document.

Comment: Hmm, I really don't know why it is not working for me. I do the same as you do. The first two times it works perfectly fine, but when changing the captionsetup the third time it does not work... But thank you very much for your help!